# Name of Windows command-line tool to refresh/reload all binaries

Tags: windows, reinstall

For the life of me I can't remember the command-line tool that looks through all installed Windows binaries and reloads them from disk if they don't match what the manifest says they should be. I'm sorry I can't describe it better than that.

For all I know it uses .inf files, or perhaps reads the registry, or both. I'm not sure. But it is a very useful tool when you suspect that, say, some .dll files have become corrupted or written to by malware.

What is the name of that tool?

Comment: Yes! The System File Checker. Thank you so much! Was the downvote from you, and if so, please explain?

Comment: No, it wasn't me.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I'll upvote. For further reading, research WinSXS, aka "The Component Store" https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251569.aspx